# What is missing from this code? I'm trying to get totals using the .count() function, but I keep getting 0s

Tags: python, list, function, arraylist, count

I am using a .csv file to import a list of lists. Now that the lists are compiled, I need to get totals and I've decided to use the .count function. The list name is attendees[]. There are 100 entries with the following items in each within the attendees list:
attendees[name, status, menu_selection, fee_paid]

When I enter this code, my totals all equal 0. I'm VERY new at coding and assume I'm missing something that will call the list. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get this to properly total these items? Here is the portion of code in question:

```
## Get Totals for each item in the attendee list.
def get_totals(attendees): 
        member = attendees.count('Member') #count of occurrences of members in attendees list
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print(f"Total Members attending:        {member}")## display totals
        guest = attendees.count('Guest')   #count of occurrences of guests in attendees list
        print(f"Total Guests attending:         {guest}")## display totals
        child = attendees.count('Child')   #count of occurrences of children in attendees list
        print(f"Total Children attending:       {child}")## display totals
        print("======================================")
        fee_paid = 21
        total_attendees = member + guest + child
        print(f"Total Attendees:                {total_attendees}") ## display totals
        total_fees = total_attendees * fee_paid
        print(f"Total fees collected:           {total_fees}") ## display totals
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        chicken = attendees.count("Chicken")#count of occurrences of chicken in attendees list
        print(f"Total Chicken entrees:          {chicken}")## display totals
        beef = attendees.count("Beef")      #count of occurrences of beef in attendees list
        print(f"Total Beef entrees:             {beef}")## display totals
        veg = attendees.count("Vegetarian") #count of occurrences of vegetarian in attendees list
        print(f"Total Vegetarian entrees:       {veg}")## display totals
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print()
        break
```

This is what I'm seeing when the code is executed:

```
Command: total
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Total Members attending:        0
Total Guests attending:         0
Total Children attending:       0
======================================
Total Attendees:                0
Total fees collected:           0
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Total Chicken entrees:          0
Total Beef entrees:             0
Total Vegetarian entrees:       0
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Without seeing the contents of `attendees` and how it is generated there is no way to answer this question.

Comment: Please mention that what is the type of `attendees` parameter. For example is it a Pandas Dataframe or is it a python dictionary?

Comment: BTW the last line of your code that has `break` in it doesn't do anything because you are not in a loop. Remove that line.

Comment: Since I'm sure it is not a Pandas Dataframe, I'm assuming it is a python dictionary. Please excuse my ignorance, this is my first coding course and I'm still learning. Thank you for noticing the break. It has now been removed.

Comment: From the first paragraph, it looks to be a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

So first clarifying the `attendees` item so we agree on that: This is a list of items where each item is yet *another* list containing, in order, `name`, `status`, `menu_selection`, and `fee_paid`.

If that's the case, each item in the `attendees` list is a list so *none* of them are going to be equal to the string `"Member"` (for example). That's why your count is always zero.

Your best bet is to construct a list of the things you *are* interested in and check that. For a status of `"Member"` and menu selection of `"Beef"`, that would go something like:

```py
def get_totals(attendees):
    # Get individual lists

    statuses = [item[1] for item in attendees]
    selections = [item[3] for item in attendees]

    member = statuses.count("Member")
    chicken = selections.count("Chicken")
```

---

Having said that, I must admit I'm a big fan of using *tailored* data structures (and type hinting) for non-trivial code, rather than the stock lists and dictionaries. Doing so allows the tools that take away a lot of Python pain points to do their job properly (things like `pylint` and `mypy`, for example).

In other words, something like this:

```py
import dataclasses as dc
import typing as typ

@dc.dataclass
class Attendee:
    """ Specific data type for a single attendee, along
        with counting match functions as needed.
    """
    name: str
    status: str
    menu_selection: str
    fee_paid: float

    def status_match(self, check_list: typ.List[str]) -> int:
        """ Allows summation of attendees matching status.
        """
        return 1 if self.status in check_list else 0

    def menu_match(self, check_list: typ.List[str]) -> int:
        """ Allows summation of attendees matching menu selection.
        """
        return 1 if self.menu_selection in check_list else 0
```

@dc.dataclass
class AttendeeCollection:
""" List type for attendees, including count methods
across the entire collection.
"""
attendees: typ.List[Attendee]

```
def __init__(self):
    self.attendees = []

def add(self, item: Attendee) -> None
    self.attendees.append(item)

def count_status(self, statuses: typ_List[str]) -> int:
    return sum([item.status_match(statuses)
        for item in self.attendees])

def count_selection(self, selections: typ_List[str]) -> int:
    return sum([item.selection_match(selections)
        for item in self.attendees])

# And any other things such as deleting or enumerating.
```

---

Then you construct the list with something like (depending on how you're reading the CSV data):

```py
attendees = AttendeeCollection()
for entry in get_csv_lines:
    attendees.add(Attendee(name=entry[0], status=entry[1],
        menu_selection=entry[2], fee_paid=entry[3]))
```

---

And your code to count things then looks more like it was written for purpose rather than just using very low-level data structures:

```py
member = attendee_list.count_status(["Member"])
guest =  attendee_list.count_status(["Guest"])

chicken = attendee_list.count_selection(["Chicken"])
chicken_or_beef = attendee_list.count_selection((["Chicken", "Beef"])
```

Now I'm not suggesting you should *change* your code to that, just that modern Python provides (but does not mandate, which is a good thing) ways to develop software that have all the advantages of statically defined languages like C++.

Comment: status has the following possibilities: Member, Guest, Child.
menu_item has the following possibilities: Chicken, Beef, Vegetarian. I think your suggestion may help. I'll give it a try and let you know. THANKS!

Comment: IT WORKED!! I changed the item to [2] instead, and everything worked beautifully! I am soooo grateful. THANK YOU SO MUCH @paxdiablo!